# javascript - Add parameters to an URL

Tags: javascript, html, utm

I have a HTML page with the UTM parameters which it can be also use for the leaf form.
http://www.example.com/tc/example.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=abc

I have English button in the page. How to add the UTM parameters after the eng URL (http://www.example.com/en/example.html)?

Thanks
YanTra

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code AFTER searching google for the title of your question

Comment: The duplicate is even overkill in your case: `<button type="button" lang="en" onclick="this.href=location.href.replace('tc',this.getAttribute('lang'))">English</button>` assuming the UTM is on the location already

Comment: Thank you mplungjan. Is it ok for below if I use href?

<a href="/promotions/en/velocity-aquabike.html" lang="en" onclick="this.href=location.href.replace('tc',this.getAttrib‌​ute('lang'))">Eng</a>

Comment: Thank you mplungjan. it works!

Comment: You said button so I changed my initial href solution to button :) - So it became incorrect. A button solution should have been `onclick="location.href=location.href....`